# How to fix Key length 256 bits in Android

Tags: java, android, file, encryption

In my application i want download encrypted file with **AES , CBC** and decrypt this file into my app!
I write below codes in my application but after application show me this error in `logcat` :

```
E/newDecryptLog: 0 : Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
```

**My password is :** `7BOF%aZQMpfJ#2wUS*S6!@K+ZB$Sz+J0`

**My codes is :**

```
public class EncryptDecryptUtils {

    public static EncryptDecryptUtils instance = null;
    private static PrefUtils prefUtils;

    public static EncryptDecryptUtils getInstance(Context context) {

        if (null == instance)
            instance = new EncryptDecryptUtils();

        if (null == prefUtils)
            prefUtils = PrefUtils.getInstance(context);

        return instance;
    }

    public static byte[] encode(SecretKey yourKey, byte[] fileData)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] data = yourKey.getEncoded();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(data, 0, data.length, KEY_SPEC_ALGORITHM);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
        return cipher.doFinal(fileData);
    }

    public static byte[] decode(SecretKey yourKey, byte[] fileData)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] decrypted;
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, yourKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public void saveSecretKey(SecretKey secretKey) {
        String encodedKey = Base64.encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        prefUtils.saveSecretKey(encodedKey);
    }

    public SecretKey getSecretKey() {
        String encodedKey = "7BOF%aZQMpfJ#2wUS*S6!@K+ZB$Sz+J0";
        if (null == encodedKey || encodedKey.isEmpty()) {
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = null;
            try {
                keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_SPEC_ALGORITHM);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            keyGenerator.init(OUTPUT_KEY_LENGTH, secureRandom);
            SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
            saveSecretKey(secretKey);
            return secretKey;
        }

        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedKey, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, KEY_SPEC_ALGORITHM);
        return originalKey;
    }
}
```

**I used with this codes for above class :**

```
@Nullable
public static byte[] decryptFile(Context context, String fileName) {
    try {
        byte[] fileData = FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.getFilePath(context, fileName));
        byte[] decryptedBytes = EncryptDecryptUtils.decode(EncryptDecryptUtils.getInstance(context).getSecretKey(), fileData);
        return decryptedBytes;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("newDecryptLog", "0 : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

But when use this run catch method and show me above error!

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can shrink your getSecretKey-method as your if-clause would never run into "false". Your encodedKey is NOT
a Base64-string but the direct input and can be used as key:

As I'm on Desktop-Java I don't know if StandardCharsets are available in Android.

```
public SecretKey getSecretKey() {
        String encodedKey = "7BOF%aZQMpfJ#2wUS*S6!@K+ZB$Sz+J0";
        return new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), KEY_SPEC_ALGORITHM);
}
```